# Moving between views without refreshing/reloading

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently looking at putting together a website with ASP.NET MVC that gives the viewer the ability to move around from page to page (view to view) without it being refreshed each time.

The way I'm currently thinking of doing it treating views as **'areas'** (or mini master pages) and using partial views in the place of views. I'll then switch the partial views in and out as needed using AJAX calls to the controller (which will load the partial view) and JavaScript.

I feel like I could have explained this better but I'm not quite sure how to phrase it, so hopefully this diagram will help somewhat:

[image]

Here's a look at my current folder structure. Index.vbhtml is acting as the aformentioned 'area'.

```
Views/
    Accounts/
        Partials/
            ViewAccount.vbhtml
            CreateAccount.vbhtml
        Index.vbhtml
```

I'm loading my partials views in using a JS function along the lines of: `nav.navigateToView("Action", "Controller")`

For example: `nav.navigateToView("ViewAccount", "Accounts"` will load the ViewAccount.vbhtml partial view onto my page.

What I'd like to know is: Is there currently a defined method for doing this, or perhaps a library I can use to aid me? If not, could you give some helpful advice on how to achieve this? I'm not convinced the method I've described will be adequate.

Apologies if this question has already been asked! I've had a tough time trying to find anything relevant on this topic. Am I missing something simple?

Thanks,
Aaron.

Comment: question ? what you want to solve?

Comment: are you looking for a single page application  architect with asp.net mvc ?

Comment: Apologies, I submitted prematurely. I've asked the question in the edit.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem here.   Load the partials into "panels" as required.  You can use `$.load`. Have each action load all the data it needs for that partial, use js namespaces and load all the js up-front.

Comment: "perhaps a library" = off-topic for SO : Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I've already described my problem in-depth and the steps I've taken to solve it (see OP).

Comment: Another way I've tried doing this is using views instead of partial views (as I was doing before) and loading those into panels as well. I thought about doing this instead because of the restrictions partial views have (not being able to use sections, for example) -- it's working well so far.

Answer (score 1):

From the description you have provided, I think what you are describing is a single page application (SPA). Needless to say, there is a bunch of articles available so sorry for not being more specific.

One approach would be to use [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/)  which is a Javascript framework, described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709766/Tutorial-for-Building-SPA-using-AngularJS) (and thousands of other sites).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Single Page Application (SPA) helps you build applications that include significant client-side interactions using HTML 5, CSS 3 and JavaScript. It’s now easier than ever before to getting started writing highly interactive web applications.

Please see [this](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application) site.